Spring Security: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS after configuring custom login page
I'm building a web app using Spring Boot and Spring Security. I've created a custom login page, but when I try to access it, I keep getting a 'Too Many Redirects' error. I've checked my browser settings and it's not a problem there. I think the issue is with my app itself
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
       User user = User.builder()
                .username("Admin")
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode("password123"))
                .roles(Set.of(Role.ADMIN,Role.OWNER))
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
              .authorizeHttpRequests(configure -> configure
                      .requestMatchers("/loginPage", "/authenticateTheUser", "/resources/**").permitAll()
                      .anyRequest().authenticated())
              .formLogin(form -> form
                              .loginPage("/loginPage")
                              .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
                              .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
                              .permitAll());
      return http.build();

  }
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <title>Service Login Page</title>
</head>

<body>

<h3>Service Login Page</h3>

<form action="#" th:action="@{/authenticateTheUser}"
      method="POST">

    <p>
        User name: <input type="text" name="username" />
    </p>

    <p>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" />
    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="Login" />

</form>

</body>

</html>

I Cleared the browser cache and cookies and also tested in incognito mode to rule out browser-related issues.

Have you created a @Controller to handle your /loginPage endpoint? Try adding .requestMatchers("/error").permitAll() because that is probably where the redirects are coming from since it requires authentication.

I tried but it still doesn't work

Try increasing the logging level and analyze the output https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/architecture.html#servlet-logging

Adding Basic Authentication to my Spring Security configuration fixed the issue. Specifically, I added the following line to my HttpSecurity setting
[https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/architecture.html#servlet-exceptiontranslationfilter][1]
http
.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
//  configurations...

